# Decoding the C declaration and making use of it

Tags: c, pointers, declaration

I'm using a GeomagnetismLibrary and one of the function declarations have a format

```
int MAG_robustReadMagModels(char *filename, MAGtype_MagneticModel *(*magneticmodels)[], int array_size)
```

For the sake of simplicity I've dumbed it down to just focus on my goal

```
void blah(int *(*a)[])
{
    (*a)[0] = malloc(sizeof(int));
    (**a)[0] = 12;
}
```

If I want to call this function I have to declare a variable like:

```
int *a[1];
blah(&a);
```

Now in my situation no matter what `a` will never have more than one element, so I don't want to declare `a` as an array, but rather as just a pointer like

```
int *a;
```

Is there any way I can type cast or dereference this variable when calling `blah` that will work as desired and not cause a segfault?

Also, how would you define that type in terms of a type cast, for example: (`int *[]*`)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would do:

```
int * b;

blah((int *(*)[]) &b);
```